# box-shadow hidden, not above

Tags: html, css

i try to put a box-shadow on a div and make it above the div below, but the shadow is hidden :  http://jsfiddle.net/fraiddo/9TMdc/

```
<div style="z-index: 2000; width: 300px; height: 130px; background-color: #eeeeaa; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); box-shadow: 0px 4px  50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">test 1</div>


<div style="z-index: 1000; width: 300px; height: 130px; background-color: #dadada;">test 2</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set z-index to both elements, but that is not enough for it to work.

One way to get it is to change your second div to position relative, and change the z-index to negative:

```
z-index: -1; 
position: relative;
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9TMdc/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the box-shadow is not displaying properly below the top div? You may need to adjust the values of the box-shadow property to achieve your desired effect.

Is this more what you were trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/K2yty/

```
    <div style="z-index: 2000; width: 300px; height: 130px; background-color: #eeeeaa; -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 4px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 4px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); box-shadow: 3px 4px  10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">test 1</div>
```

Also, don't forget to change the values for each browser specific value: moz, webkit, etc.

Comment: i would said that the div "test 2" make the box-shadow of div "test 1" hidden

Comment: If the lower div is overlapping and hiding the box-shadow of the upper div, you may just need to add a margin to the bottom of the upper div. Here is an updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/K2yty/2/ I added 'margin-bottom: 10px;' to create the separation between the divs. Is that what you were looking for?